# Is there a `flet` for commands in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to dynamically redirect one command to another one within a
certain function using around advice, something like this:

```
(defun f1 (arg)
  (interactive (list (read-from-minibuffer "F1: ")))
  (message "f1: %S" arg)
  arg)
(defun f2 (arg)
  (interactive (list (read-from-minibuffer "F2: ")))
  (message "f2: %S" arg)
  arg)
;; Function that invokes the f1 command
(defun myfunc ()
  (call-interactively 'f1))

;; I want myfunc to invoke f2 instead whenever it would invoke f1
(defadvice myfunc (around f1-to-f2 activate)
  (flet ((f1 (&rest args) (interactive) (call-interactively 'f2)))
    ad-do-it))

(myfunc)
```

However, this gives an error `(wrong-type-argument commandp f1)`,
indicating that when `flet` redefined the `f1` function, it didn't
process the interactive form and treat it like a command, so it can't
be invoked by `call-interactively`.

Is there a variant of `flet` that will work for commands in this way?

(Here are the actual redefinitions I want to do:)

```
(defadvice org-metaleft (around osx-command activate)
        (flet ((backward-word (&rest args)
                (interactive)
                (call-interactively #'move-beginning-of-line)))
          ad-do-it))

(defadvice org-metaright (around osx-command activate)
        (flet ((forward-word (&rest args)
                (interactive)
                (call-interactively #'move-end-of-line)))
          ad-do-it))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're bumping into a silly bug in flet: the macroexpansion of flet will have: `(lambda (&rest args) (progn (interactive) (call-interactively 'f2)))`.  Notice the spurious `progn` added in there, which "hides" the `interactive`.

To get more control (and avoid cl.el at the same time), you can do:

```
(defadvice myfunc (around f1-to-f2 activate)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'f1)
             (lambda (&rest args)
               (interactive) (call-interactively 'f2))))
    ad-do-it))
```

Answer (score 2):

*(Edit: The `cl-letf` macro can do this natively in modern emacs. The answer below might still be useful for old versions.)*

Well, if there wasn't before, there is now:

```
(require 'cl)
(require 'cl-lib)
(defmacro command-let (bindings &rest body)
  "Like `flet', but works for interactive commands.

In addition to the standard `(FUNC ARGLIST BODY...)' syntax from
`flet', this also supports `(FUNC NEW-FUNC)' as a shorthand for
remapping command FUNC to another command NEW-FUNC, like this:

  (defun FUNC (&rest ignored)
    (interactive)
    (call-interactively NEW-FUNC))

\(fn ((FUNC ARGLIST BODY...) ...) FORM...)"
  (declare (indent 1))
  (cl-loop for binding in bindings
           collect (list (car binding) nil) into empty-bindings
           collect (if (symbolp (cadr binding))
                       ;; Remap one command to another
                       `(defun ,(car binding) (&rest args)
                          (interactive)
                          (call-interactively ',(cadr binding)))
                     ;; Define command on the fly
                     (cons 'defun binding))
           into defun-forms
           finally return
           `(flet (,@empty-bindings)
              ,@defun-forms
              ,@body)))
```

In action:

```
(defadvice myfunc (around f1-to-f2 activate)
  (command-let ((f1 f2))
    ad-do-it))
(myfunc)
```

That code now invokes the `f2` command using `call-interactively`, as desired.

Comment: `(require 'cl-lib)` is not sufficient because `flet` is not provided by cl-lib (but by cl.el instead).

Comment: Thanks for that reminder. `cl-lib` was for the loop macro, and I forgot that `flet` wasn't built in. Also, I keep forgetting which of the `flet` variants use dynamic binding and which use lexical binding. Obviously I need dynamic binding here.

Comment: @RyanThomson: Yes, it's rather messy/confusing.  The story behind them helps, tho: `cl-lib` is newer, hence `cl-flet` is newer than `flet`, so its "natural" that `cl-flet` is the lexical one (since lexical scoping is newer in Emacs).  As for `letf`, the `f` comes from `setf` rather than from "let function", so it's really just a way to "set...restore", hence dynamic scope.